# How can I estimate gaussian (mixture) density from a set of weighted samples?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, estimation, gaussian

Assume I have a set of weighted samples, where each samples has a corresponding weight between 0 and 1. I'd like to estimate the parameters of a gaussian mixture distribution that is biased towards the samples with higher weight. In the usual non-weighted case gaussian mixture estimation is done via the EM algorithm.

Is there an implementation (any language is OK) that permits passing weights? If not, how can I modify the algorithm to account for the weights? If not, how to incorporate the weights in the initial formula of the maximum-log-likelihood formulation of the problem?

Comment: Is "EM" error minimization, or something else entirely? Also, there are *many* numeric and analysis packages ranging for basic and general to highly specialized. It might help if you said something about your problem domain and preferred environment. Fortran? C++? Java? Python? Are you OK learning a major new tool like R or root?

Comment: Ok, then my preferred language would be Python. But any of the above languages except root (never heard of it) would also be ok. 
EM stands for Estimation Maximization and is general iterative scheme that can be used for estimation of the parameters of a gaussian mixture model from data.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that method and can't make any specific recommendations.

Comment: Try asking on http://math.stackexchange.com/ . This looks more like a Math question than a coding question to me.

Comment: Did anyone get to implement this? I'm struggling with the same problem. Actually, I'm trying an implementation that I found in a research paper but it's not working (the program usually ends up with a singular covariance matrix)

Answer (score 4):

I've just had the same problem. Even though the post is older, it might be interesting to someone else. honk's answer is in principle correct, it's just not immediate to see how it affects the implementation of the algorithm. From the Wikipedia article for [Expectation Maximization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation-maximization_algorithm) and a very nice [Tutorial](http://www.ee.washington.edu/techsite/papers/documents/UWEETR-2010-0002.pdf), the changes can be derived easily.

If $v_i$ is the weight of the i-th sample, the algorithm from the tutorial (see end of Section 6.2.) changes so that the $gamma_{ij}$ is multiplied by that weighting factor. 
For the calculation of the new weights $w_j$, $n_j$ has to be divided by the sum of the weights $\sum_{i=1}^{n} v_i$ instead of just n. That's it...

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate a weighted log-Likelihood function; just multiply the every point with it's weight. Note that you need to use the log-Likelihood function for this.

So your problem reduces to minimizing $-\ln L = \sum_i w_i \ln f(x_i|q)$ (see [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood#Principles) for the original form).

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion as no other answers are sent.

You could use the normal EM with GMM (OpenCV for ex. has many wrappers for many languages) and put some points twice in the cluster you want to have "more weight". That way the EM would consider those points more important. You can remove the extra points later if it does matter.

Otherwise I think this goes quite extreme mathematics unless you have strong background in advanced statistics.

Comment: This doesn't work when you either have a lot of points or intrinsically non-integer weights. As it happened to me to have both: a histogram of millions of points with non-integer weights...

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar solution related to gaussian kernel estimation (instead of a gaussian mixture) of the distribution.

The standard [gaussian_kde](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html#scipy.stats.gaussian_kde) does not allow that but I found a python implementation of a modified version here
http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2013-May/034580.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this analysis can be possibly be done via the `pomegranate` (see [Pomegranate](https://pomegranate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) docs page) that supports a weighted Gaussian Mixture Modeling.

According to their doc:

> weights : array-like, shape (n_samples,), optional
> The initial weights of each sample in the matrix. If nothing is
> passed in then each sample is assumed to be the same weight.
> Default is None.

Here is a Python snippet I wrote that can possibly help you do a weighted GMM:

```python
from pomegranate import *
import numpy as np

# Generate some data
N = 200
X_vals= np.random.normal(-17, 0.9, N).reshape(-1,1) # Needs to be in Nx1 shape
X_weights = w_function(X_vals) # Needs to be in 1xN shape or alternatively just feed in the weight data you have

pmg_model = GeneralMixtureModel.from_samples([NormalDistribution], 2, X_vals, weights=X_weights.T[0])
```

[[Figure] Observed versus weighted distribution of the data we are analyzing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xL87i.png)

[[Figure] GMM of the weighted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hMdf.png)